# Checking if a particular value exists in the Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an Android application using `Firebase` realtime database. When a new user registers on my app, that user's data is saved in the Firebase database.

A user has to provide the following details to register:

1. Full Name
2. Email
3. Username
4. Password

#### Database Structure

[image]

Whenever a new user tries to register, I have to make sure that each user's username is unique so I check the database if the `username` entered by the user already exists in the database or not.

To do this, I wrote the following method:

```
private boolean usernameExists(String username) {
     DatabaseReference fdbRefer = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/"+username);
     return (fdbRefer != null);
}
```

My logic behind this method is that if `getReference` method cannot find reference to the specified path, it will return null so that I can return whether `fdbRefer` is `null` or not. If `fdbRefer` is `null`, then it means that `username` doesn't exist in the database.

#### Problem

Problem with this method is that it always returns `true` whether the entered `username` exists in the database or not. Which led me to believe that `fdbRefer` is never `null`.

This brings me to my question...

#### Question

What does `getReference` method return when it can't find the specified path in the `firebase` database and what's the correct way to check if the `username` already exists in the database or not?

Comment: i really appreciate your way to ask question in SO community , thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To check the existence of a user, please use the below code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userNameRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("Nick123");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //create new user
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
userNameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

You can also use a Query to achieve the same thing like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Users").orderByChild("userName").equalTo("Nick123");
query.addValueEventListener(/* ... */);
```

This is another approach which is looping through the entire `Users` node but is not just using a direct reference to a single user. This option is more likely to be used when you are using as a unique identifier beteeen users the `uid` instead of the user name (as you do right now). So if your database structure might looks similar to this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- Users
        |
        --- uid
             |
             --- userName: "Test User"
             |
             --- emailAddress: "user@email.com"
```

The second solution is the recommended one.

There is also another solution which involves you to create another node named `userNames`, in which you can hold only the unique user names. Please also find below the corresponding security rules:

```
"Users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
    ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'",
    "userName": {
      ".validate": "
        !root.child('userNames').child(newData.val()).exists() ||
        root.child('userNames').child(newData.val()).val() == $uid"
    }
  }
}
```

But since in this case, your user name is already the name of the node, I recommend you go ahead with the first one.

Comment: Please see also the difference between this two approaches. Using the first solution will help you save bandwidth.

Comment: Can you please explain what `if(!dataSnapshot.exists())` is for ?

Comment: The `dataSnapshot` object represents a snapshot at the following location: `Firebase-root -> Users -> Nick123`. The best solution is to use `exists()` method directly on the `dataSnapshot` to check for existens. When you are using a Query, you are looping through the whole object and this means waste of bandwidth. I gave you also the Query solution, maybe you'll need in the future.

Comment: @AlexMamo for the first solution, what if users node has push tokens before username e.g. when we add users with push() method. I think My dataSnapShot always gets null because of this

Comment: @ninbit If it has used  the pushed id then you should change this `.child("Nick123")` into this: `.child(pushedId)`. But to store user details under a pushed id is not a very good practice. You should use the `uid` like this: String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(); and `rootRef.child("Users").child(uid)`, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo well then how to add _uid_ instead of _pushedId_? when I use push() method, it automatically generates _pushedId_ under _users_ and then adds the user data under that _pushedId_

Comment: @ninbit The question that you are asking is not related to this one. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: @AlexMamo I wait for your solution at: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772812/checking-if-a-user-already-exists-at-firebase-realtime-database)

Comment: @AlexMamo How do you know that first solution is not looping but the second is? Can you share any Firebase docs that confirm that? Thanks.

Comment: @RedM First solution is using a reference that is pointing directly to a specific user while the second is using a query that searches the entire object to find the corresponding user.

Comment: i am doing push value not add value like that here is pushed so i get uniq id for that node then how can i check user exist or not ?

Comment: @MehulTank In that case you should use Peter's answer.

Comment: @AlexMamo: Which of those approaches (first appraoch and query appraoch) saves more bandwith? And in the query approach  what do I have to write into the brackets `query.addValueEventListener(/* ... */);`? Further, when using the query approach together with the interface for reading the data that you explained in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg&ab_channel=AlexMamo, where shall I execute the query statement? Inside the `readData` method from the video?

Comment: @VanessaF 1) If the query returns a single object, then you'll use the same bandwidth. 2) You have to add a ValueEventListener object. 3) I'm not sure I understand the question. But if you have further questions, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: @AlexMamo: Thanks for your answer. When using your approach from this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg&ab_channel=AlexMamo) the whole sub-database users is returned. When using the query approach it always returns an empty object. This is why I have 2 questions: 1) Do you also have a video where you explain in Java how to handle the query approach asynchronously? 2) Is your query `Query query = rootRef.child("Users").orderByChild("userName").equalTo("Nick123");`  quering one-level below "Users" (so all User entries) or 2 levels (will it find Nick123 or "Nick123")?

Comment: @VanessaF I don't have a video regarding a query, but it should behave the same. If you have a hard time implementing that, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you. 2) Yes, it only queries one level below.

Comment: @AlexMamo: Thanks for your answer. To be totally honest so far your answer has not helped me. I am still trying to transfer it to my case (but I upvoted your video on Youtube). You said that the query queries only one level below. How can I query two levels below meaning that every User whose attribute "username" is equal to "Nick123" should be returned? Or each user, whose attribute "password" is "111111" should be returned. I think this is the problem I am facing with the query. If I can solve that, I will upvote your answer.

Comment: @VanessaF To understand 100% your use case, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo(Nick123).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      if(dataSnapshot.exist() {
         //username exist
          }
        }
```

You have to use `orderbychild` and `equalto` to check the value if it is there.
If you dont use `orderbychild` and `equalto` then it will just check if `username` child node is there and doesnt care about the value.

this `orderByChild("username").equalTo(Nick123)` is like saying:

```
WHERE username=Nick123
```

Answer (score 3):

Works Perfectly for me

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                .orderByChild("username")
                .equalTo(username);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0) {
                    //username found

                }else{
                    // username not found
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking for the exists of the reference you can use orderBy query to check whether username exists already

orderByChild('username').equalTo(username) query would return data if some data already exists else it will return null.

Answer (score 2):

Check it like this...

```
    fdbRefer.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
if(dataSnapshot.exist() {
//username exist
}
else {
//username doesn't exist
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already got a solution to your problem, I will try to explain why your code was not working.

> ```
>  DatabaseReference fdbRefer = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/"+username);
> ```

You might be thinking that in the above statement `fdbRefer` will be null if "Users/"+username is not present in the database.
But actually, this statement will only store a path to the specified field in `getReference()`. So when you check for `fdbRef!=null`, it is always true because `fdbRefer` will hold value something like 'https://.firebase.com/Users/Nick123.