# How to check for existing data in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

[image]

above is my firebase node tree.
here is my code:

```
private fun attemptAdd(){
    var focus: View? = null
    var cancel: Boolean = false
    var prefix: String  = prePrefView.text.toString() + prefText.text.toString()
    var sp: SimPrefix

    //checks for the length of the input
    if(prefText.length()<2){
        prefText.error = "invalid length"
        cancel = true
        focus = prefText
    }

    mDatabaseReference.child("simnumbers")
            .orderByChild("simPref")
            .equalTo(prefix)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
                        sp = it.getValue(SimPrefix::class.java)!!
                        if(sp.simCard.equals(prefix)){ //checks if there is already a node with the same data
                            prefText.error = "already exists"
                            cancel = true
                            focus = prefText
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {

                }
            })

    if(cancel){
        focus?.requestFocus()
    }
    else{ //if all is valid, proceed to the next method.
        addPrefix()
    }
}
```

What I assume here is that it doesn't seem to enter the listener since it always
proceeds to the next method allowing the user to enter the same existing data.

Comment: [Have you seen this question? The answers here might help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893328/checking-if-a-particular-value-exists-in-the-firebase-database?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I provide java code you can change into kotlin and also put your condition in to onDatachange method..

```
     Query query1=reference.child(reference.getKey()).child("simnumbers").orderByChild("simPref").equalTo(prefix);
    query1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // here place your condition
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: do I also need to put the condition in an iteration ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to check if data exists:

```
  mDatabaseReference.child("simnumbers")
        .orderByChild("simPref")
        .equalTo(prefix)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
                    sp = it.getValue(SimPrefix::class.java)!!
                       }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {

            }
        })
```

The datasnapshot is at `simnumbers`, then it will check if that snapshot exists in the database and if the child `simPref` is equal to the value provided

> `public boolean exists ()`
>
> Returns true if the snapshot contains a non-null value.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#exists()

Comment: what did you get

Comment: actually I got it, I just removed the .equalTo() and moved the if(cancel){}else{} inside the onDataChanged() but outside of the iteration. But still, thanks!

Comment: @ronan since the answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as correct, thank you!