# Checking if a user already exists at firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get the [Alex Mamo's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47893879/4176989) in order to check whether a unique value exists in my database but the snapshot gets always null. The solution is here:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userNameRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("Nick123");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        //create new user
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userNameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And my database looks like this:

```
users
    (auto-generated push token ID)
        fullname
        username
        gender
        ...
```

I don't know whether it's the right method but I used push() method for adding the user object to the database and this method generates push token ID like above.

So, in order not to create duplicate users, what should I change with the above solution? Is there a better method to do this? Maybe like checking the firebase uid with some firebase auth methods?

**UPDATE**
My database screenshot:
[image: database]
As you see the string just below 'users' is not the same as user's uid.

Comment: You get null because you do not have a child called Nick123 `child("Nick123");` as I explained in the second part of my answer. Since you are using randomid instead of userid then check the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the best practice when it comes to save user details into the database. First, you should implement [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) and then in order to check if a user exist in your database, you should use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        //create new user
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.d("TAG",error.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

So the key for solving this problem is to call the `child()` method and pass the UID as an argument instead of calling the `push()` method that generates an random unique identifier.

Comment: I have already implemented firebase authentication but I needed to store some extra user  info. So I saved the user details into the database. So snapshot still gets null with your solution

Comment: I added the screenshot of my database

Comment: Is `null` and it always be `null` because you are using as unique itenfier the pushed id and not the id provided by Firebase authentication as I adviced you in my answer, right?

Comment: And the child is `users` and not `Users`. See capital `U` vs lower case `u`?

Comment: But I dont know how to use uid as identifier in the database and I ask you how to do it in the comments

Comment: Basically you should use `child(uid)` instead of `push()` method. Basically you should replace the `push()` with `child(uid)`, right? If it is not ok, please add the code that you are using to add the user to the database and I'll show you how, ok?

Comment: being newbie around here is hard :) thanks for the patient replies, I didnt know child() method adds the data, just knew setValue() method does this. I think it is better to update your answer with adding this comment for other users

Comment: @ninbit `child()` method adds a new child down in your tree, so you're welcome and cheers!

Comment: @AndréKool In the solution above, I already have used `.child(uid)` and **not** used the `push()` method. Thanks!

Comment: This is only for reading, not writing. OP is using push() to save user info in their question so for this answer to work they will have to change that.

Comment: @AndréKool Ok that's fine. Just updated my answer by adding this info for a better understanding. Thanks André!

Answer (score 5):

If you have this database:

```
users
(auto-generated push token ID)
    fullname
    username
    gender
```

Then to check if user exists you need to do the following:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userNameRef = rootRef.child("users");
Query queries=userNameRef.orderByChild("fullname").equalTo("Nick123");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   if(!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
       //create new user
    }
 }

    @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
queries.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

First if you have `users` lowercase letter, then inside child add `users`, then you need to use a query to be able to check if the fullname is equal to Nick123.

---

Usually the database is structured like this:

```
users
  userId
     fullname: Nick123
```

The attributes are `key:value`, the key is the identifier and Nick123 is the value, so inside the `child()` method you need to write the identifier which is `fullname` and not Nick123.

Then since you are able to get the userId, you can do this:

```
FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser =FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId=currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userNameRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("fullname");
userNameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){...}
```