# Sync contacts firebase

Tags: android, performance, firebase, android-contacts

I'm developing a feature in my app to help users find friends who are registered and are in the contact list on the phone. Something like what instagram does here:
[image: instagram example]

Does firebase have any way to synchronize and compare contacts? I think that comparing each phone contact with each database contact will not be very efficient in terms of performance.

Comment: Might you be able to publish an answer by example? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does firebase have any way to synchronize and compare contacts?

It does not. You should create your own system for that.

> I think that comparing each phone contact with each database contact will not be very efficient in terms of performance.

Is not. In fact, is quite simple and efficient since Firebase SDK provides a method that can help you simply verify if a user exist or not in the database, this method is called [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#exists()).

For more informations, please also see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893328/checking-if-a-particular-value-exists-in-the-firebase-database/47893879)**.