# How to check if a value exists in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

before reading I'm a newbie trying to learn android development so don't go hard on me, please.

I have this Realtime database firebase :

[image]

I'm trying to check if the entered email exists , i've tried a method but it did not work out for me.

I tried this method :

```
private boolean checkIfExistes() {


    reference.child("Users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(Email.getText().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                CheckExists =true;
            else
                CheckExists =false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    if (CheckExists)
        return  true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

it always returns false though even if the email exists. Help please.

Comment: addListenerForSingleValueEvent is asynchronous and returns immediately.  The callback you provide to it doesn't get invoked until some unknown time later, which means that your function always immediately returns false.  Try putting log statement inside the onDataChange callback to see what I mean.

Comment: i tried and turned out as you stated ,what would be the solution tho ?

Comment: The solution is to only use the result in the callback itself, or a functions it calls, passing the result to it.

Comment: Can you help me and write it as code , as that i'm not fully understanding what to do.

Comment: I think you should go for getting data into Iterable and then compare for the field you want

Comment: @DeepPatel can you please tell me how to do so , i'm really new and self learning , so it would be really helpful if you wrote me the code to do so.

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893328/checking-if-a-particular-value-exists-in-the-firebase-database/47893879)** out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
boolean CheckExists =false;   //declare and assign default value in global scope

reference.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> userChildren = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

        for (DataSnapshot user: userChildren) {
            User u = user.getValue(User.class);      //make a model User with necessary fields

            if(u.email.equalsIgnoreCase(Email.getText().toString())){
                CheckExists =true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for getting it right , but another problem popped up ,CheckExists returns to false after exiting the addListener method idk why

Comment: check updated answer. I declared and assigned value for boolean in global scope, value will be changed only if matching record gets found.

Comment: Actually is it seems its because of the asynchronous computation the method finishes its call before even getting the result of the firebase. i've tried a solution Alex Mamo put in another question , but it didn't work ou..

Comment: Fixed it by putting the whole code in the method instead of waiting for its callback

Answer (score 0):

```
private DatabaseReference rootRef,userRef;
```

get the initialize firebase in oncreare method

```
rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
userRef = rootRef.child("Users");
```

here the code for checking email exist or not

```
userRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailEdt.getText().toString())
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    hideProgress();
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"User already exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        UserLogin user = new UserLogin(emailEdt.getText().toString(),profilePath);
                        DatabaseReference db = userRef.push();
                        db.setValue(user);
                        //Log.d(TAG,"user key is::: "+db.getKey());
                        prefs.savEmail(emailEdt.getText().toString());
                        prefs.savProfileUrl(profilePath);
                        prefs.savKey(db.getKey());
                        openMainActivity();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    hideProgress();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I think this ways goes if i'm using firebase auth , but i'm not , i'm using my own way and already tried the idea of whats written , thanks for your try to help me but this won't work in my case.