# How to check child in firebase for username *and* password with Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I read the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) about this, but the documentation conveniently left the detail about `equalsTo` examples out. I also see some other related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893328/checking-if-a-particular-value-exists-in-the-firebase-database), but none give me answer about how to filter children with two values.

So the database is more or less like this:

```
users: {
  as9d8f7a89sdf7a: {
    username: admin,
    password: test123,
    timestamp: 38410238912,
    priviledge: { }
  },
  asd9fasd90f8a0s: {
    username: moderator,
    password: hello456,
    timestamp: 12937129383,
    priviledge: { }
  }
}
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
databaseRef.child("users").childEqualsTo("username", usernameTf.text).childEqualsTo("password", passwordTf.text)
```

But from what I gathered, the closest thing I can do to search for this is:

```
databaseRef.child("users").orderByChild("username").equalsTo(usernameTf.text)
```

And then manually loop for the result's password if I can find any match? Is this correct?

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen alright thanks!