# Infinite cycle on Firebase with Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

So, my app does is a QR code scanner that adds the QR id to the current user UID. I first verify if the user already did that scan; if not, that id is added to the firebase table; otherwise, it will create that table.
This is my code:

```
private fun infoAdd(str2: String, view: View) {
        val  currentUser = auth.currentUser?.uid
        val postReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("organsUsers")
        val dbView = postReference.child(currentUser.toString())
        val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val org = snapshot.child("uOrgans")
                if (org != null) {
                    val post = org.getValue(String::class.java)
                    dbView.child("uOrgans").setValue("$post,$str2")
                } else {
                    dbView.child("uOrgans").setValue(str2)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            }
        }
        dbView.addValueEventListener(postListener)
    }
```

The str2 it's the string of the QR id.

This is what happens to Firebase:

[image: FIREBASE IMAGE]

Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I first verify if the user already did that scan; if not, that id is added to the firebase table; otherwise, it will create that table.

It doesn't make any sense because in both cases you are "setting" the value of `str2` into the database, that's why you see that behavior of highlighting that operation in yellow. Because a Firebase Realtime Database is a NoSQL database and is structured as pairs of keys and values, every node is a Map, which means that when using a setValue() operation, the old value is replaced with the new one.

If you want to check if the value of `uOrgans` exists, then update it for example, please use the following lines of code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val uidRef = rootRef.child("organsUsers").child(uid)
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val org = snapshot.child("uOrgans")
        if(org.exists()) {
            val post = org.getValue(String::class.java)
            dbView.getRef().updateChildren(mapOf("uOrgans" to "$post,$str2")) //Update it
            Log.d("TAG", $post,$str2)
        } else {
            uidRef.child("uOrgans").setValue(str2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

If doesn't exist, the `str2` is added to the database.

One thing to mention, if `uOrgans` doesn't exist, none of its parents (organsUsers and the UID) nodes will not exist.

Comment: I tried, but the updateChildren only accept Map<>, not String...it's giving me an error.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, my bad. Instead of passing a String, pass a Map like in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Can you help me in one more thing? How can i verify if tha id already exists? If it already exists, i dont need to add it.

Comment: Good to hear that. Sure, please check my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893328/checking-if-a-particular-value-exists-in-the-firebase-database/47893879).

Comment: I already saw your post, but it doesn't work...i've tried some diferent ways. Is there a way to find a string on that variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "find a string on that variable"?

Comment: I already figured out. I just splitted that string I got from database. One more thing...do you have any experience with recycler view on fragments? Because I've tried many ways and none of them worked...

Comment: I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp-Clean-Architecture-MVVM) might help.

Comment: I just saw, but i didn't found the fragment and the recyclerview. I'm also new at this, so I can't really translate from java to kotlin. Do you think i should do a new question?

Comment: @GuilhermeFaure Yes, a new question would be more helpful.

Comment: I've already posted a new question...Will you check it out?

Comment: @GuilhermeFaure I've seen it and already answer it.