# getvalue() in query return null from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[the databas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxCnf.png)

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button readBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readBtn);
        EditText testInputTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testInputTxt);
        
        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Login");
        Query query = rootRef.orderByChild("LoginUserName").equalTo(testInputTxt.getText().toString());



        readBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        String passwordUser = snapshot.child("LoginPassword").getValue(String.class);
                        testInputTxt.setText(passwordUser+"tatata");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

the query works fine it detects that the user is existexists but i wanted to retrieve the value of LoginPassword but it returns null i tried the for DataBase....:snapshot code but it won't  detect

Comment: can you provide more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a Query object, it means that you can potentially get multiple results from the database. That being said, you have to loop through the results using a call to `.getChildren()` as seen in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference loginRef = rootRef.child("Login");
Query query = loginRef.orderByChild("LoginUserName").equalTo(testInputTxt.getText().toString());
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String passwordUser = ds.child("LoginPassword").getValue(String.class);
                testInputTxt.setText(passwordUser+"tatata");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Please also note that if two users have the same "LoginUserName", then your `TextView` will always display the value of the last one. So always be sure to have unique user names. To check if a user name already exists, please check my answer from the following post:

- [Checking if a particular value exists in the Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893328/checking-if-a-particular-value-exists-in-the-firebase-database/47893879)

Comment: I would like to add question after i change the code the tag gave me this :" D/TAG: Client is offline" How can i fix this?

Comment: Most likely your client is offline. If you have a hard time solving it, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.